# Convert linkage matrix to tree (scipy.cluster.hierarchy.to_tree, python3)

Tags: python, tree, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I want to translate a linkage matrix to a tree (to convert it in further steps to newick format). The linkage matrix looks like this:

```
[[ 0.  1.  1.  2.]
[ 2.  4.  4.  3.]
[ 3.  5.  6.  4.]]
```

When I run the code ('from ete3 import Tree'):

```
T = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.to_tree(Z)
root = Tree()
root.dist = 0
root.name = "root"
item2node = {T: root}
```

the program terminates at item2node with the error message:

> Exception "unhandled TypeError"
>   unhashable type: 'ClusterNode'

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use `T` as the key of a dictionary.  It is not a hashable object.